# Is it possible to have these functions exposed for testing?

Tags: javascript

Given that I'm extending an existing module and it uses the module.exports in the way shown below, can I even call the `start` methods from (mocha) tests?

I suspect that there's no decent way to tap into it - and that's ok. I'd just rather test these if I am able to and would love to know how to do it if possible.

```
const NodeHelper = require("node_helper");
module.exports = NodeHelper.create({
    start: function() {
        //do stuff
    };
});
```

Edit: [NodeHelper](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/blob/master/modules/node_modules/node_helper/index.js) returns a function that appears to be "extended":

```
NodeHelper.create = function(moduleDefinition) {
    return NodeHelper.extend(moduleDefinition);
};
```

Comment: what is node_helper ?

Comment: What object do you get on `NodeHelper.create`?

Comment: Updated with the info

Comment: How about `require('path/to/your/module').start()`?

Comment: @Phil - TypeError: require(...).start is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Looking closer at the linked code, it uses [Resig's `class.js`](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/blob/master/js/class.js) so you probably need to create an instance to call the prototype methods, ie

```js
const YourNodeHelper = require('path/to/your/module')

const yourNodeHelper = new YourNodeHelper() // create instance here
yourNodeHelper.start()
```